# ValueError: y has only 1 sample in class 0, covariance is ill defined. While QDA classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, quadratic

I'm getting the error at the title when I try to classify my dataset.

My dataset is a 4 input 4 output dataset. My input and output is array and each array has 414 value in it shape is (414,4)

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis


names = ['pH', 'BOI5', 'AKM', 'KOI']
dataframe = pd.read_excel ("C:/Users/hayri/Desktop/aabb.xlsx") 
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4:8]

Y = np.argmax(Y, axis=1)
qda = QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(store_covariance=True)
qda.fit(X,Y)
```

I'm new at Machine Learning so every information would be helpful

Comment: post the complete error

Comment: File "C:\Users\hari\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\discriminant_analysis.py", line 687, in fit
    'is ill defined.' % str(self.classes_[ind]))

ValueError: y has only 1 sample in class 0, covariance is ill defined.

Answer (score 0):

From your stacktrace it seems that you only have one example of class 0 which makes the covariance matrix calculation for QDA ill defined. Try to print the number of element in each class to verify that this is the case.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the 0 class, Now the error I'm getting is ValueError: bad input shape (331, 4), Cant I fit a (331,4) array into qda

Comment: Your Y should be a simple vector with one of 4 values corresponding to the classes. Your X is a matrix with the row being one observation and the columns corresponding to the features you calculate (pH, BOI5, AKM, KOI). Here you can see a working example:https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.qda.QDA.html

Comment: What are your input and what are you trying to predict? You should also close this question and write another one to keep the questions focused.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that one of your classes (namely class 0) has only one sample in the training set, so this make the calculation of the svd step in the QDA algo impossible (because you are trying to compute svd for a null matrix, see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/discriminant_analysis.py) for more info)